# How do I prove that a group with one generator and a single relation is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_m}$?

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

That is, if $G= \langle a \, | \, a^m = e \rangle$, then $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_m}$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Other users will be better able to answer your question if you share what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Define the map $\phi$ from $G$ to $\mathbb Z_m$ by by $\phi(a^n) = n$ mod $m$ . Show this is a well defined isomorphism.

Comment: This is clear, but what about the trivial relation $a = a$?  Food for thought.

Comment: @hardmath It seems that the group is the free group with one generator, i.e. $(\mathbb Z,+)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a surjection from Z to G which sends 1 to the generator of the group, the kernel is a subgroup mZ of Z, thus G =Z/mZ